# How can I compare data in two spreadsheets with appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two spreadsheets named as **source_data** and **target_data**. I am comparing them both with the following code, however I want this code to return the exact cell address where the changes have been made. Also what exact change is there, the previous value of that cell and new value of that cell. Both sheets have same range as I am already copying the data of source_data with another function to the target_data sheet.

```
function updateSheet() {
  const actualSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dtyM-Q3ej4q3NORbPAgTNlymcdLlBCXd4wbNbMMc8fE");
  const copiedSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14xvI7fUVxsMNMfAPWP-WUcoX2bo35S93CylC6RnjP7k");
  let sourceValues = actualSheet.getSheetByName("admanager").getRange("A:D").getValues().filter(String)
  let targetSheet =  copiedSheet.getSheetByName("admanager")
  let targetRange =  targetSheet.getRange("A:D");
  let targetValues = targetRange.getValues().filter(String)
  let diff = targetValues.showDif(sourceValues)
  Logger.log(diff);
  // targetRange.clearContent();
  // targetValues = (diff && diff.length) ? targetValues.concat(diff) : targetValues;
  // targetSheet.getRange(15, 5, targetValues.length, targetValues[0].length).setValues(targetValues)
 }

Array.prototype.showDif = function (array) {
    let that = this;
    return array.filter(function (r) {
        return !that.some(function (x) {
            return r.join() === x.join();
        })
    })
}
```

This code is giving the output in an array which returns the whole row where there is a difference.
output >>

```
1:54:04 PM  Info    [[a, bcd, lorem ipsumdh dchdbcbdj. bhjdbc.], [b, language, Lorem ipsum hbfhbfhdv]]
```

Kindly let me know how can I modify this code in such a way that it returns the exact Cell location and its value instead of an array with the whole row?

Comment: Have you tried making a map of values and indexes, and then feeding that map into your showDif function?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to check the difference between the sheet of "admanager" in "actualSheet" sheet and the sheet of "admanager" in "copiedSheet" sheet using Google Apps Script.
- You want to return the differences as the coordinates and each value of "actualSheet" sheet and "copiedSheet" sheet.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
function updateSheet() {
  const a1Notation = "'admanager'!A:D"; // Please set the range.
  const sourceSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  const targetSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

  const [sourceValues, targetValues] = [sourceSpreadsheetId, targetSpreadsheetId].map(id => SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getRange(a1Notation).getDisplayValues());
  const diff = sourceValues.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (c != targetValues[i][j]) ar.push({row: i + 1, col: j + 1, sourceValue: c, targetValue: targetValues[i][j]});
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  console.log(diff);
}
```

- In this sample script, the cell values of 2 Spreadsheets of `sourceSpreadsheetId` and `targetSpreadsheetId` are compared, and when the cell values are different, the cell coordinate and each value are returned.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is obtained.

```
[
  { row: 1, col: 1, sourceValue: 'a1', targetValue: 'updated' },
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)